# Convert NA values to ? automatically while loading

Tags: weka

Is there a way to automatically convert NA values to ? in weka while loading .csv files?
Or do we have to use some other script/program to either replace them with ? or a blank space before loading into weka.

Any help or suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Links are broken.  Is there a way to either fix the links (or remove the two paragraphs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not believe Weka has a way to do this conversion.  This is the case because Weka's native format is .arff files.  **In .arff files, missing values are denoted with a "?".**  When a .csv file is loaded, it expects missing values to also be denoted by "?".

Depending on your method of using Weka I suggest:

1. For the Weka GUI, use "**find and replace" in a simple text editor** to change "NA" to "?" before loading the .csv into Weka.
2. For the Weka Java API, write a method to preprocess your ".csv" file before handing it over to the Weka .csv loader.