# Not able to load CSV file in weka

Tags: csv, weka

I am not being able to load csv file using weka, I have removed each and every special symbol even using text editor, still no luck. I am attaching the file, I will be obliged if solve this problem.

It shows "Wrong number of values, Read 31, expected 27, read token[EOL], line 3"

link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By7zyIPDD6HJMmthWnZLSUk5aFE

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code you're working with. Don't have us download a file.

Comment: There is no code, I just want to load the csv file using Weka interface, and the above link is for the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have planty of empty fields in your file and if you download it as .csv even the header gets three commas at its end.
e.g. your 6th line:

> ,Doug Walker,,,131,,Rob Walker,131,,Documentary,Doug Walker,Star Wars: Episode VII    The Force Awakens             ,8,143,,0,,,,,,,,,12,7.1,,0,,,

Simmilar to the suggestion in this post you could try s.th. like notepad++ or another text editor to replace ",," by ",?," to fill up your gaps.

[Convert NA values to ? automatically while loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210756/convert-na-values-to-automatically-while-loading)

I did this and then you get in your first row two question marks as column names wich obviously doesnt work, so change the first row to look like this:

> color,director_name,num_critic_for_reviews,duration,director_facebook_likes,actor_3_facebook_likes,actor_2_name,actor_1_facebook_likes,gross,genres,actor_1_name,movie_title,num_voted_users,cast_total_facebook_likes,actor_3_name,facenumber_in_poster,plot_keywords,?,num_user_for_reviews,language,country,content_rating,budget,title_year,actor_2_facebook_likes,imdb_score,aspect_ratio,movie_facebook_likes,**additionalColName1,additionalColName2,additionalColName3**

if you try now to import your data weka starts telling you which lines it doesn't like and why. Btw. you did not "removed each and every special symbol"!
After removing a fiew lines with e.g. the Ç character it worked.

Thats just an ugly workaround, try filling the empty values and find a regular expression or a better way to save your file to remove the last three commas of every line, i was just too lazy for now. But i could load it into weka and that's what you wanted (: